# Full page iframe on mobile browsers

Tags: android, html, css, iframe, mobile

I'm trying to fully embed a page inside an iframe in another page. The page where it's embedded is supposed to look exactly like when browsing the source page directly.

I've tried many different frame/iframe and style combinations that I've found, all either here from stackoverflow or from various blogs, they all work on desktop but all look different on mobile.

Comparison between the two sites on android:

- [Going to the side directly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8Lf7.png)
- [Same site inside an iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKDqm.png)

It looks the same on desktop browsers, but on mobile the page inside the iframe always looks smaller and doesn't fill the whole screen.

From what I unterstand the problem comes from the css on the src page, but I can't edit that.
Is it possible to get this working on mobile browsers without making changes to the embedded  site itself?

Update:

The site I want to embed is something like this: **office074.wix.com/vitalpharma**

What I've tried already:

- www.dev-explorer.com/articles/full-page-iframe
- cloud.mobify.com/docs/working-with-iframes/
- www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/02/27/making-embedded-content-work-in-responsive-design/
- stackoverflow.com/questions/17838607/making-an-iframe-responsive
- stackoverflow.com/questions/26194040/how-does-this-responsive-iframe-container-snippet-work/26194041#26194041
- stackoverflow.com/questions/7902960/creating-a-full-screen-iframe
- stackoverflow.com/questions/325273/make-iframe-to-fit-100-of-containers-remaining-height

(Can't post more then 2 direct links, sorry)

Answer (score 4):

For anyone searching on this, just include the original meta tags (from the iframe site) in your html. This will scale your page to match the content inside your iframe.

Answer (score 3):

Including original meta tags(from the iframe site) in outer HTML worked out for me.

```
var viewPortTag=document.createElement('meta');
viewPortTag.id="viewport";
viewPortTag.name = "viewport";
viewPortTag.content = "width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;";
window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(viewPortTag);
```

Include above lines of code inside the script tag of outer HTML. This will scale iframe content as per the resolution of mobile browser.

Answer (score -1):

Add the following in the head tags of the iframe page:

```
<style>
body {margin:0; padding:0;}
iframe {margin:0; padding:0; width:100%; height:100%;}
</style>
```

This should allow the iframe to fill the page.

Comment: I alredy tried that, that's what most other posts on the web suggest, but it doesn't work with my embedded site. The results all end up like in the image I linked.

Comment: And there is NO other content on the page? Have you tried adding `html {margin:0; padding:0;}`?

Comment: no, also doesn't work, and no other content on the site. I also added a link to the site I want to embed, as well as links to the stuff I've already tried.

Comment: Directly visiting the website reveals the problem: the actual website doesn't stretch to fill the display, meaning it's impossible to achieve what you want. I'm not too sure how to fix it but a search for something like 'stretch content to fill page html' might work.