# How to hide mobile browser address bar on page with full-page iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, wysiwyg

I have a webpage whose only content is an `<iframe>` pointing to a web app hosted elsewhere. For the user, visiting the external site directly should be indistinguishable from visiting the iframe version.

So far, everything works, except a nagging issue on mobile browsers.

The problem is that when a mobile user scrolls the content of the iframe, the mobile browser's address bar does not hide automatically as it normally does. This leads to part of the content being out-of-view.

I think this is because the top-level document *hasn't scrolled*, only the content of the iframe has.

This is in the external page's `<head>`:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1" />
```

This is the iframe tag:

```html
<iframe src="https://external.com/" frameborder="0" class=""></iframe>
```

This is the CSS i'm applying to it:

```css
iframe {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 1000;
    pointer-events: all !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

I tried the solution [mentionned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26681145/full-page-iframe-on-mobile-browsers) to copy the child's meta viewport tag over to the parent, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Could you mask this issue by using a simple function to show/hide the IFRAME div on scroll?

```
$(window).scroll(function() { // when the page is scrolled run this
    if($(this).scrollTop() != 0) { // if you're NOT at the top
        $('#youriframeDIV'); // add
    } else { // else
        $('#youriframeDIV'); // remove
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this wouldn't work because the iframe is the *only* element on the parent page. I edited my question to make this clearer